# Google cloud functions: How to get access tokens in cloud function for the required scope?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

We are deviating from datastore [scheduled export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export) mechanism (google suggested) and adopting to schedule datastore backup via [cloud scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) which will target HTTP [cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/). Here, we want use cloud function to export our datastore entities to certain storage bucket. The reason for this deviation from standard mechanism is that, we want to avoid duplicated non-app specific code in all our services.

As per [docs](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/datastore/v1/), the managed export and import service is available only through Datastore mode Admin API (REST, RPC) and requests require OAuth 2.0 authorization.

In cloud function, to access datastore API `https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<APP ID>:export`, we require `access_token` from scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore`.

In standard GAE application code, using python27 runtime, we can get access_token as per below example -

```
from google.appengine import app_identity

access_token, _ = app_identity.get_access_token('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore')
```

But, cloud functions have Python37 runtime. So, importing `google.appengine` gives error as `error as error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'`

How can we get `access_token` for the required scope? (any one of below scopes) -

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

Please suggest reference to Python code/document. Thanks.

Comment: I read that library `oauth2client` is deprecated and should use `google.oauth2` instead but, still an issue. Cloud function throws an error `module 'google' has no attribute 'oauth2'`

Comment: Datastore export and import can also be done via client API (Python). Below is the example,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JWT and Access Token are two separate things. JWT is composed of three parts ie a header, a claim set, and a signature. On the other hand, an access token can only be obtained from the Authorization Server. Please 'Addendum' section of [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests) google document. I created a cloud function by passing service account details to encode into JWT( with a header and payload).

```
signed_jwt = jwt.encode(payload, key, headers=additional_headers, algorithm='RS256')
decoded_signed_jwt = signed_jwt.decode("utf-8")
```

In order to obtain the access token, please refer the following code snippet.

```
token_endpoint = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'
token_req_data = {
    'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
    'assertion': decoded_signed_jwt
}
token_post_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(token_req_data).encode("utf-8")

access_token_req = urllib.request.Request(token_endpoint, token_post_data)
access_token_req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
result = urllib.request.urlopen(access_token_req)
json_str = result.read()
```

This json string should include access token. Use this access token in request header of for required API. Please update your payload for signed JWT as below, otherwise you may not be able to get a valid JWT.

```
'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
'aud': 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'
```

Hope this helps and I thank to Google support for some part of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Python 3.4 or higher](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation) is supported by `google.appengine`. The error is releated to `google-api-python-client` not being installed as a dependency when the Function runs.

Try adding it to [requeriments.txt](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python) on the Clound Functions editor page.

You can also use [google-auth](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) by `import google.auth`

Comment: Please observe edit in the question. I have specified my `requirements.txt` now. Can you please help?

Comment: When you use `google-auth` you have to use `import google.auth`. Seems by your error code that you are importing `oauth2` insted of `auth`.

Comment: okay, how can I get access token with `import google.auth`? I tried with `credentials, project_id = google.auth.default('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore')` but `credentials.token` is `None`

Comment: Please refer `google-auth` documentation :- https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#module-google.oauth2.service_account

Comment: Could you edit your question to better see the updated code? It seems that you are running `credentials = gce.AppAssertionCredentials(
   scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write')` to get the credentials, but in your comments you seem to use `credentials, project_id = google.auth.default('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore')`

Comment: updated code. The necessary scope is `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore'`. Access Token from there should help me hit datastore API.

Comment: I think the best course of action in this case would be to open a new question as this one has since become confusing. I see you are trying to use the REST API with the request library but you are missing some fields on the request body. Open a new question with all the new information gathered here. I think you are going to get more help on that way.

Comment: Thank you Nahuel for all the help. I have edited my question. Probably it was unnecessarily specific, edited to generalize it.